# Fast Fourier Transform Algorithm and Technical Analysis

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, transform, fft

My Mini Practice Project requires me to do:

1. Download stock prices.
2. Detrend stock prices.
3. Smooth detrended stock prices.
4. Apply FFT algorithm.

The Mini Practice Project Python code can be seen below:

```
#Python code: Download the Daily Stock Prices from Yahoo Finance 
from matplotlib.finance 
import quotes_historical_yahoo 
from pylab
import * import numpy as np import
scipy.signal as sc import
matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
ticker='AAPL' begdate=(2013,12,6) enddate=(2015,12,20)
data = quotes_historical_yahoo(ticker, begdate, enddate,asobject=True, adjusted=True)
aapl=data.aclose[1:]
np.count_nonzero(aapl)
plt.plot(aapl)
plt.title(‘Apple stock price movement’)

#Python code: Detrend stock prices
detrend=sc.detrend(aapl)
plt.plot(detrend)
plt.title(‘Apple stock detrended prices’) 

#Python code: Smooth Detrended Apple Stock Prices 
w=np.blackman(20) 

#we selected 20 the parameter of the blackman window function 
y=np.convolve(w/w.sum(),detrend,mode='same')
plt.plot(y) plt.title(‘Blackman window function for detrended Apple stock
price’) 

#Python code: Apply FFT Algorithm 
fft=abs(rfft(y)) plt.plot(fft)
plt.title(‘FFT Algorithm applied to Apple stock price’)
```

When I type >>> fft, the result should be:
array([ 31.29635197, 2706.46455209, 1093.11797192, 904.02261366, 582.27538238, 282.87694269, 244.95336969, 501.27771573, 247.04690328, 554.24978967, 115.67400179, 270.14245787, 194.51970654, 179.0406388, 302.98350318, 170.32131932, 51.39420044, 87.25308608, 87.15654977, 39.34619432])

I keep getting a code error: from matplotlib.finance is an invalid syntax. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib.finance 
import quotes_historical_yahoo
```

should be on the same line like so:

```
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo
```

Alternatively, you can break lines:

```
from matplotlib.finance \
import quotes_historical_yahoo
```

Comment: Thank, castle-bravo. Now, I get an error syntax -> from pylab What should I do with this?

Comment: @JohannesBambangWirawan I imagine it's the same error you saw before? It's caused by putting `from ...` and `import ...` on different lines. You need to put `from pylab` and `import *` on the same line. Different import statements should be on different lines, so you'll need to move the numpy import to a different line than the pylab one.

Comment: OK, done. Now, I have another problem. plt.title(‘Apple stock price movement’) -> Code Analysis Invalid character in identifier. Do I need to do something in the plt.title?

Comment: @JohannesBambangWirawan In the code you posted, you're using backticks `\`` instead of single quotes `'` or double quotes `"`. You need to use either the single or double quotes and not backticks when formatting strings.

Comment: Done, I changed it to single quotes '
There are 3 Code analysis:
from pylab import * -> Code analysis 'from pylab import *' used ; unable to detect undefined names.
import pandas as pd -> Code analysis 'pandas as pd' imported  but unused.
fft=abs(rfft(y)) -> Code analysis 'rfft' may be undefined , or defined from star imports: pylab.
Please advise.

Comment: @JohannesBambangWirawan, In general, to find out what module to import rfft from, use Google. To test individual imports, open up a terminal and try to import the function you're after; no need to run all your code. For the time being, know that `rfft` is under `np.fft`, so you would call `np.fft.rfft`.

Comment: I got this from the Lecturer. Python FFT Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673496/python-numpy-fft-or-rfft-to-find-period-of-a-wave-instead-of-its-frequiency

 

To view the Fourier Analysis of American Express look here: http://www.gregthatcher.com/Stocks/Fourier/Analysis/AXP 

 

If you want to peer inside the "black box" of DFT/FFTs -- the mathematics involved in actual algorithms -- then review this ebook_CRC_Press__Inside_The_FFT_Black_Box_Serial_And_Parallel_Fast_Fourier_Transform_Alg.pdf

Comment: My lecturer said please us Quandl or download csv.  Yahoo finance calls may not work. :-( This what causes 3 Code analysis error. This means I cannot use import quotes_historical_yahoo. I need to find a way to import historical quotes from Quandl.

Comment: @JohannesBambangWirawan If you have new problems, please post a new question. If you're going to make a living as a quant or whatever, then you should be able to make some progress by yourself; reading error messages and using Google are the minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I'll Google the solution and rewrite the code in a different post.